# Regex to flip and merge all backslashes except the first one

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to write regex that will flip and merge all backslashes except the first one.

Something like this:

```
 C:\a\b\c\d\e         --> C:/a/b/c/d/e
 C:\a\\b\\\c\d\\\\\\e --> C:/a/b/c/d/e
 C:/a///b//c/d//////e --> C:/a/b/c/d/e
 C:\a/\/b/\c/d//\///e --> C:/a/b/c/d/e
 C:/a/b/c/d/e         --> C:/a/b/c/d/e
```

but

```
\\my_share\a\b\c\d/e             --> //my_share/a/b/c/d/e
\\my_share\\\a\\\\b\c\\\//\\d\e   --> //my_share/a/b/c/d/e
\\/\my_share\\\a\\\\b\c\\\\\\d\e --> //my_share/a/b/c/d/e (if multiple '\' or\and '/' in the front - put two //)
\my_share\\\a\\\\b\c\\\\\\d\e    --> /my_share/a/b/c/d/e (if one '\' or\and '/' in the front - flip it)
my_share\\\a\\\\b\c\\\\\\d\e     --> my_share/a/b/c/d/e (if no '\' or\and '/' in the front - don't do anything)
```

How to do it in powershell? `$my_path -ireplace "\\", "/"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
$s = 'C:\a\b\c\d\e'
[regex]::Replace($s,'^([\\/]{2,})|[\\/]+',{param($match) If ($match.Groups[1].Success) { '//' } Else { '/' }})
```

The regex matches

- `^([\\/]{2,})` - Group 1 consisting of 2 or more `/` or `\` chars at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `[\\/]+` - 1 or more `/` or `\` chars anywhere else.

If Group 1 matches, `//` is used as a replacement, else `/`.